# Term for a dilation of fixed distance, not fixed scale

Tags: geometry

Is there a term for increasing/decreasing the size of a shape by X units in the perpendicular direction of every point in the shape?  I know that scaling the shape is called dilation; I'm looking for a different term.

Comment: What's "the perpendicular direction"? Perpendicular to what?

Comment: Perpendicular to each point.  Select the point and N points on either side of it, calculate the linear regression through those points,  and then find the line perpendicular to that regression line that also goes through the selected point. Go out (or in) X units from the point along that line.

Comment: Wait, what? Is the shape just a set of finitely many points?

Comment: Yes, for my purposes it would be a finite set of points.

Comment: If the shape is a curve this is known as a *[parallel curve](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_curve)* or *offset curve*; the term generalizes naturally to parallel/offset surfaces.

Comment: This phrasing is disturbing for me. To me scaling is scaling, or maybe an homothety. The term dilation can be interpreted as dilation/erosion from mathematical morphology, and if you use a sphere as the structural element, it can coincides with the offset shapes... (shape as opposed to the curves mentioned by @Rahul , the way a circle is distinct from a disk... dunno the proper phrasing for that)

Answer (score 0):

What you describe sounds like the [Minkowski sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_addition) of your shape and a disk whose radius is the fixed distance you mention. The result is a set containing all those points which are no more than that radius away from your original shape. Its boundary consists of [offset curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_curve) of your original boundary.